# Sorting by subquery result using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to translate this SQL query into Hibernate Criteria but am not quite sure how as I am very new to Hibernate.

```
SELECT header.*,
(SELECT items.end_date from
    subTable sub,
    ItemTable items
    WHERE items.sub_id = sub.sub_id
    and header.header_id = sub.header_id
    order by items.end_date desc
    limit 1) as latestEndDate
from headerTable header
order by latestEndDate desc;
```

I can create the subQuery but I am at a loss with how to merge it into the master query.

```
Long headerId = getHeaderId();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(dataaccess.model.Item.class, "item");

DetachedCriteria headerSubQuery =
    DetachedCriteria.forClass(dataaccess.model.Header.class, "header")
.setProjection(Property.forName("header.headerId"))
.add(Restrictions.eq("headerId, headerId));

DetachedCriteria subTableQuery =
    DetachedCriteria.forClass(dataaccess.model.SubTable.class, "sub")
.setProjection(Property.forName("sub.subId)).add(
    Property.forName("header").in(headerSubQuery));

criteria.add(Property.forName("sub").in(subTableQuery));
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("endDate"));
criteria.setMaxResults(1);

List<Items> items = criteria.list();
```

*HeaderTable and SubTable have a 1:1 relationship and is in place only for legacy reasons. SubTable owns Items, but because of the 1:1 relationship, the HeaderTable also owns the Items (HeaderTable -> SubTable -> Items).

That query returns the item with the latest endDate. I want to be able to query the header table and sort by the latest endDate for one of it's items (as in the SQL query above) using Hibernate.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this by adding another field to my model of Header and using the @Formula annotation to pass in my SQL query.

```
@Formula("(SELECT items.end_date from "
    + "subTable sub, "
    + "ItemTable items "
    + "WHERE items.sub_id = sub.sub_id "
    + "and header.header_id = sub.header_id "
    + "order by items.end_date desc "
    + "limit 1)")
private Date latestStartDate;

public getLatestStartDate() {
    return latestStartDate;
}
```

This allowed me to append an order to my criteria:

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("latestStartDate"));
```